# how to drop dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tips are there for dropping column and rows depending on some condition.
But I want to drop the whole dataframe created in pandas.
like in R : rm(dataframe) or in SQL: drop table

This will help to release the ram utilization.

Comment: What do you mean? you mean something like `del df`? this is no different to any other object in python, you could also do `df = None`

Comment: Do you have, for example, evidence of some sort that "ram utilization" is a problem? Generally creating a new object and binding it to a variable will allow the deletion of any object the variable previously referred to. `del`, mentioned above, removes both the variable and any object it referred to. (this comment is an over-simplification).

Comment: @holdenweb My scenario is the dataset I am working with is huge. So once loaded( with pd.read_csv()) the system is getting slow. And after splitting and some processing , I want to remove the bigger dataset and work with the small one.That's why I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally creating a new object and binding it to a variable will allow the deletion of any object the variable previously referred to. `del`, mentioned in @EdChum's comment, removes both the variable and any object it referred to.

This is an over-simplification, but it will serve.